# Ошибка динамической маршрутизации flask

Tags: python, flask

Создал простой проект с @app.route(‘/home/int:id‘), в html файле создаю href=“{{url_for(‘home’, id=id)}}”
Ожидаю получить что-то такое localhost/home/5, но почему-то только localhost/home/?id=5

Как это можно решить?

Comment: @app.route(‘/home/<int:id>‘)

Answer (score 0):

В `href="{{url_for(‘home’, id=id)}}"` вы передаёте `id` как параметр для дальнейшей обработки.

Если хотите получить `localhost/home/5`, то используйте `href="{{ url_for(f‘home/{id}’) }}"`.